# py2exe command prompt exe change shell window size and colors?

Tags: python, cmd, py2exe

i'm trying to change the compiled exe's icon and such using this script for my setup.py:

```
setup(name = "Program Title",
      version = "1.0",
      options = {"py2exe" : {"compressed" : 1,
                             "optimize" : 2,
                             "bundle_files" : 2 }},

      console=[{'script': 'program.py',
                "icon_resources": [(0, "icon.ico"), (1, "icon.ico"), (42, "icon.ico")]
                }],
      description = "some description",
      author = "author",
      author_email ="some@email.com",
      license = "wxWindows Licence",
      url = "http://some.website.here,
      )
```

but unfortunately, when it compiles the .ico didn't carry over (is in same dir as program.py and setup.py)

Also i was wondering if it is possible to change the command prompt look a bit by changing the background color and size of the window as it pops up through py2exe... I checked the documentation, but it's not really that helpful. Also window'd mode doesn't work for my program, it requires console.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these tutorials for a colored console:

[Bring Colors to the Windows Console with Python](http://www.burgaud.com/bring-colors-to-the-windows-console-with-python/)

[Change Windows Console Character Attribute](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496901-change-windows-console-character-attribute-color/)

[The Console Module](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm)

---

For the icon, try this suggestion from [CustomIcons](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/CustomIcons):

"Important Note For Adding Multiple Icons On Systems Where This Method Is Not Working: After much research (blood, sweat, and tears), I have found why icons with multiple sizes sometimes do not work. The truth is, is that the order matters. When making the icon, add the larger icon sizes first, then the smaller ones. (e.g. png2ico icon.ico icon_128x128.png icon_64x64.png icon_48x48.png icon_32x32.png icon_16x16.png)"

Comment: anything about changing the default popup window size? or changing the console size after it opens?

Comment: This `Console` module should be able to open a new console window at a specified size.  Not sure it is possible to modify an existing console window in MSWidows at all (via python) but I could be wrong.  Heres the [Console module docs](http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm).